# Lint for Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lint

Does exist some Lint tool for Rails application as a whole?

For example, `ruby-lint` doesn't see declarations in other modules if modules have been referenced by mentioning them in `require` clause in `application.rb` file.

RubyMine also doesn't see them when doing code inspection.

Comment: Hm...How about tests?

Comment: @NicoSantangelo Tests and linting are two completely different things, with almost completely opposite purposes.

Comment: Yup they're are not the same, my comment wasn't an answer. I don't think there's is a Rails linting tool so I gave him what I use. It's true that they check different things, but exercising the code can be useful regardless :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

no, there is not.

ruby is a dynamic language, so all you can do in a rails project is to lint syntax in ruby source files with stuff like `ruby -v` aka ruby-lint.

you can use a tool called [rails-best-practices](http://rails-bestpractices.com/) to evaluate your code. but like the name says, it's only best practices and is more soft rules than hard linting.

of course there are many more code analysis tools available like [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop), they all go into a similar direction.